# How to extract the non-empty elements of list in R?

Tags: r

I have very big list, but some of the elements(positions) are NULL, means nothing inside there.
I want just extract the part of my list, which is non-empty. Here is my effort, but I faced with error:

```
ind<-sapply(mylist, function() which(x)!=NULL)
list<-mylist[ind]

#Error in which(x) : argument to 'which' is not logical
```

Would someone help me to implement it ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the logical negation of `is.null` here. That can be applied over the list with `vapply`, and we can return the non-null elements with `[`

```
(mylist <- list(1:5, NULL, letters[1:5]))
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5

# [[2]]
# NULL

# [[3]]
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"

mylist[vapply(mylist, Negate(is.null), NA)]
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5

# [[2]]
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
 myList <- list(NULL, c(5,4,3), NULL, 25)
 Filter(Negate(is.null), myList)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care of the result structure , you can just `unlist`:

```
unlist(mylist)
```

Comment: I needed a simple way to only take out the non-null value from a list and this does the trick! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What the error means is that your brackets are not correct, the condition you want to test must be in the `which` function :

`which(x != NULL)`

Answer (score 1):

One can extract the indices of null enteries in the list using "which" function and not include them in the new list by using "-".

```
new_list=list[-which(is.null(list[]))]
```

should do the job :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
list(NULL, 1, 2, 3, NULL, 5) %>% 
     purrr::map_if(is.null, ~ NA_character_) %>% #convert NULL into NA
     is.na() %>% #find NA
     `!` %>%     #Negate
     which()     #get index of Non-NULLs
```

or even this:

```
list(NULL, 1, 2, 3, NULL, 5) %>% 
     purrr::map_lgl(is.null) %>% 
     `!` %>% #Negate 
     which()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
MyList <- list(NULL, c(5, 4, 3), NULL, NULL)

[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
[1] 5 4 3

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
NULL

MyList[!unlist(lapply(MyList,is.null))]

[[1]]
[1] 5 4 3
```